# Symfony4 - How to filter EntityType Field with Voter

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4, symfony4-voter

I need to filter options displayed in an EntityType Field with Voters.

I have a User Entity which has some relations to CustomerGroup, CustomerEntity and CustomerSite.
I have a Voter on, for example, Customer Group. I can filter the results depending on the current user's Role in a list view. I use an 'array_filter' function to make it work. Example on User Object :

```
        $users = array_filter($users, function (User $user) {
            return $this->isGranted('view', $user);
        });
```

I've googled a lot of pages without any success ! I tried to create a custom function in the CustomerGroupRepository and call it from the query_builder option in FormType : it throws an error. See just below :
CustomerGroupRepository.php :

```
    {
        $customerGroups = $this->createQueryBuilder('cg')
            ->orderBy('cg.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

        $customerGroups = array_filter($customerGroups, function (CustomerGroup $group) {
            return $this->security->isGranted('view', $group);
        });

        return $customerGroups;
    }
```

And the Buildform function with the query_builder option :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('isActive')
            ->add('CustomerGroup', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => CustomerGroup::class,
                'label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function(CustomerGroupRepository $er) {
                    return $er->findAllGranted();
                },
                'is_granted_disabled' => $options['is_granted_disabled'],
                'is_granted_attribute' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                'is_granted_subject_path' => 'parent.data',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false
            ]);
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetDataEntity'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmitEntity'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetDataSite'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmitSite'));
```

The Error I get :

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Repository\CustomerGroupRepository::App\Repository\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Entity\CustomerGroup, array given
```

The GroupVoter.php :

```
namespace App\Security\Voter;

use App\Entity\CustomerGroup;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\Voter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class GroupVoter extends Voter
{
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        // replace with your own logic
        // https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html
        return in_array($attribute, ['view', 'edit'])
            && $subject instanceof CustomerGroup;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        // if the user is anonymous, do not grant access
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return false;
        }

        // ... (check conditions and return true to grant permission) ...
        switch ($attribute) {
            case 'edit':
                // logic to determine if the user can EDIT
                // return true or false
                break;
            case 'view':
                return $this->canView($subject, $user);
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param CustomerGroup $object
     * @param User $loggedUser
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canView(CustomerGroup $object, User $loggedUser)
    {
        if($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
            return true;

        elseif($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_GROUP_MANAGER'))
        {
            if($object === $loggedUser->getCustomerGroup())
                return true;
        }
        elseif($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ENTITY_MANAGER'))
        {
            if($object === $loggedUser->getCustomerEntity()->getCustomerGroup())
                return true;
        }
        elseif($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_TECHNICIAN'))
        {
            $customerSites = $loggedUser->getCustomerSites();
            foreach ($customerSites as $site)
            {
                static $retour = false;
                if($site->getCustomerEntity()->getCustomerGroup() === $object)
                    $retour = true;
            }
            return $retour;

        }



        return false;
    }
}
```

The UserFormType.php :

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\CustomerEntity;
use App\Entity\CustomerGroup;
use App\Entity\CustomerSite;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\CustomerGroupRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;


class UserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('isActive')
            ->add('CustomerGroup', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => CustomerGroup::class,
                'label' => 'name',
                'is_granted_disabled' => $options['is_granted_disabled'],
                'is_granted_attribute' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                'is_granted_subject_path' => 'parent.data',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false
            ]);
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetDataEntity'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmitEntity'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetDataSite'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmitSite'));

    }

    ...

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'is_granted_attribute' => null,
            'is_granted_subject_path' => null,
            'is_granted_hide' => false,
            'is_granted_disabled' => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

The options available in CustomerGroup field in the form are not filtered by Symfony.
I can see all CustomerGroups even if my ROLE doesn't allow them.

EDIT : Maybe I should use the 'choises' attribute. I need to access the CustomerGroupRepository to do that !

Thanks for your help !

Best,

Julien

Comment: "it throws an error" - so why don't you tell us the error message and work with us on fixing the error? also I don't know where you get the `is_granted_...` properties from ...

Comment: you are not able to filter choices after hydration, there is an open pull request which could allow this in symfony core repo. You should filter the entities by yourself in FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA.

Comment: I updated my post. Rawburner : I'm gonna check your advice.

Comment: regarding your error. don't do `getArrayResult` (returns array of arrays) but instead `getResult` (returns array of objects). so your filter approach might just work ;o) however, I believe the `query_builder` property expects a query builder to be returned from the callback ;o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your tips !

Finally, I managed to make it works by making a custom "FindByGranted" function in a repository.
Fo example :

```
public function findAllGranted()
    {
        $customerGroups = $this->createQueryBuilder('cg')
            ->orderBy('cg.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()->execute();

        $customerGroups = array_filter($customerGroups, function (CustomerGroup $group) {
            return $this->security->isGranted('view', $group);
        });
        return $customerGroups;
    }
```

I then call this function from the formType.

Thank you all.

Regards,